# Grid view not updating when array is updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm creating a program where every time a user clicks a button, which is in the MyPond view, a new fish is added to an array, which appears as a FishView in a grid in the Journal View.

MyPond, where the user clicks a button to generate a new fish:

```
struct MyPond: View {
    @State var newFish = Fish()
    
    var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                            newFish = Fish()
                            Journal().addFish(fish: newFish)
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Click here to fish")
                            .padding()
                    }
              }
       }
}
```

The Fish Object:

```
struct Fish: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = fishNameGenerated.randomElement()!
}
```

Journal, which is currently not displaying any fishViews:

```
class Fishies: ObservableObject {
    @State var array:[Fish] = []
}

struct Journal: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fishArray = Fishies()
    
    public func addFish(fish: Fish) {
        self.fishArray.array.append(fish)
        for fishy in fishArray.array {
            print(fishy.name)
        } // currently not printing anything
    }
        
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10)]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(fishArray.array){ fish in
                    FishView(fish: fish) //Displays fish as fish view. FishView code is working
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the grid in Journal is not updating and remaining blank, even when the button creating a new fish object is pressed. How can I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject` where you own the object. Use `@StateObject`

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you are not seeing any fish appear is because there is no `Journal` in the body of `MyPond`. You are simply creating a new `Journal` every time the button is tapped, but this doesn't cause it to be shown as part of the view. And since you are creating `Fishies` in `Journal`, you start with a new collection with every new instance.

So there are quite a few things you need to fix:

- Create the `Fishies` object as a `@StateObject` in `MyPond`. You don't need the `newFish` state variable.
- Move the `addFish` function from `Journal` to `Fishies`.
- Call `Fishies.addFish` from the button callback.
- Include a `Journal` view inside the body of `MyPond`.
- Pass the `Fishies` object to the `Journal` view, for it to observe.
- Inside `Fishies`, the array should be `@Published`, not `@State` (you only use `@State` inside a `View`).

Here is an updated version which works a bit better:

```swift
struct Fish: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = fishNameGenerated.randomElement()!
}

class Fishies: ObservableObject {
    @Published var array = [Fish]()

    public func addFish(fish: Fish) {
        array.append(fish)
//        for fishy in fishArray.array {
//            print(fishy.name)
//        }
    }
}

struct MyPond: View {
    @StateObject var fishArray = Fishies()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                fishArray.addFish(fish: Fish())
            } label: {
                Text("Click here to fish")
                    .padding()
            }
            Journal(fishArray: fishArray)
        }
    }
}

struct FishView: View {
    let fish: Fish
    var body: some View {
        Text(fish.name)
    }
}

struct Journal: View {

    @ObservedObject var fishArray: Fishies

    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10)]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(fishArray.array) { fish in
                    FishView(fish: fish)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```